# loading one activity whilst having multiple activities

Tags: java, android

So i am creating an application right now on Android studio. I have two activities which are my 'Main activity' and also my 'second activity' I have finished with my 'Main activity' and i am now creating my second. I haven't yet created an action which will let me go from my first activity to my second. However i wish to only load my second activity to check how it looks.

I am using a samsung phone to load it because i dont know too much about this emulator stuff, so i went with the option of using my samsung phone. Is there a way of loading just my second activity without it loading my first?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit the `AndroidManifest`**:**

Remove these lines from the `MainActivity`

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then add your new `SecondActivity` if you have already added in manifest then edit it to look like this **:**

```
<activity
  android:name=".SecondActivity"
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will make the `SecondActivity` as launcher activity (started on click of an icon in app list).

Comment: Okay @Zraja I am glad you solved your challenge **Happy coding!**.